# Any DB listing all languages in multiple languages?

Tags: database, multiple-languages

I'm going crazy, I don't seem to find any file (CSV, SQL, whatever) listing "all" the languages' names in different languages.

Something like:

```
id,lang_en,lang_es,lang_pt,lang...
en,english,inglés,inglês,...
es,spanish,español,espanhol...
```

Do you know any?

Cheers!

Comment: If you think there's a list of all languages then you're mistaken. The very definition of "language" is hazy at best. Do dialects count? What about regional accents that are utterly impenetrable to others?

Comment: Which database are you using?  The language support of each database varies from one to the other.  As far as a general list of all languages, never seen one.  Just look at https://translate.google.com/, these are the ones they translate for, and there are MANY more!

Comment: A file including the most common languages would be fine... I need to use it in a website, and I would like language names to appear in the user language. I cannot believe it doesn't exist when loads of websites use it.